# New To the concept of Object Oiented Programming

Tags: python, class, oop, time

I'm wondering if I even needed to create this class to store the information I need to be able to grab out of the time module. Is this bad code? I don't even know if this is a really good question to ask. or am I just over complicating things? I basically only need the date and time because I'm going to be creating a sign_in/out method that creates a timestamp for a user when they sign in or out. Like a punch card system basically. Thanks In advance 
Gerald

```
import time
the_time = time.localtime()

class Clock():

    def __init__(self, year, month, day, hour, minute, second ):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.second = second

list1 = []
for t in the_time:
    list1.append(t)
print(list1)



clock_list = Clock(list1[0],list1[1],list1[2],list1[3],list1[4],list1[5])

print(clock_list.minute)
print(clock_list.second)
```

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, but personally I wouldn't use a class for something like this...

Comment: You would normally use ``datetime`` for that. Do not re-invent the wheel.

Comment: You are over-complicating things.  `time.localtime()` returns an object with named attributes.  Just `print(the_time.tm_min)`, etcetera.  No need for the class.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer before this was closed. This is obviously too complicated for this dummy problem, but there are certainly use cases where you would want a real class to represent your time object. Imagine a punch card system where you can modify each punch, but the original values should remain in history to be reverted and a report can be generated on each modified punch.

Comment: is there a difference between datetime, and time to get the time and date from the system clock? so another words I'm basically over complicating this by creating a clsss? I guess sign_in/out time could be just something like sign_in_out = time.localtime()  ? IDK I'm still learning very new to this haha

Comment: How do I close this? I thank all for your input :)

Comment: @GeraldLeese check [this snippet out](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1660883) for an example of what building in a class can get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a strictly computer science point of view, you don't ever *need* to use object-oriented programming - if the language you are using is turing-complete, then you can write all the code you want with a few simple instructions. The point of OOP is that it makes larger programs a lot easier to manage, through hiding implementation details from the rest of your program.

In your case, what you are doing is not wrong per se, but if that's all your program does, then you don't need OOP. If your program starts to become larger, though, then using OOP could be worthwhile.

One of the hard parts of learning OOP is knowing when to make an abstraction, and knowing what abstraction to make. Once you've tried writing a few programs using OOP this should start to become clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your input :) I figured I'm probably over complicating things for myself. ive been reading about Tkinter as ill probably use it to make a sign in button and text box widget still got a lot to learn :P lots of trial and error :P